# How to extrude polygon in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, react-three-fiber

In general I want the user to be able to click on a horizontal plane, and create a polygon, which is then automatically extruded up. I am using three.js and react-three-fiber, and I can add spheres where the user clicks but when it comes to extruding it I get very weird results (the extrusions go towards the x or z direction not up).

Here is my function:

```
 const handleFloorClick = (event) => {
        const mouse = new THREE.Vector3();
        const { offsetX, offsetY } = event;
    
        // Normalize mouse coordinates to the range [-1, 1]
        mouse.x = (offsetX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
        mouse.y = -(offsetY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
    
        // Update the raycaster with the normalized mouse coordinates
        raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
    
        // Intersect the ray with the floor to get the 3D coordinates
        const intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(floorRef.current);
    
        if (intersects.length > 0) {
            const { x, y, z } = intersects[0].point;
            console.log('Mouse click location:', x, y, z);
        

            // Create a new circle mesh
            const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.12, 32);
            const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 'black' });
            const sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

            // Position the circle at the clicked coordinates
            sphere.position.set(x, y + 0.1, z); 

            // Add the circle to the scene
            scene.add(sphere);

            // Save the circle in state for later removal or manipulation
            // Save the sphere and its coordinates in state
            setSpheres((prevSpheres) => [
                ...prevSpheres,
                {
                    mesh: sphere,
                    coordinates: { x, y, z },
                },
            ]);

            // Create a polygon mesh when at least three spheres are present
            if (spheres.length >= 2) {
                const points = spheres.map(({ coordinates }) => new THREE.Vector3(coordinates.x, -1, coordinates.z));
                console.log('Points:', points);
                const shape = new THREE.Shape(points);
                const geometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry(shape);
                const polygonMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 'red'});
                const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, polygonMaterial);


                console.log(mesh)

                // Add the new polygon mesh to the scene
                scene.add(mesh);
                setPolygonMesh(mesh);

                // Log polygon position for debugging
                console.log('Polygon position:', mesh.position);

                // Extrude the polygon to create a 3D shape
                const extrusionSettings = { depth: 30, bevelEnabled: false};
                const extrudedGeometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(shape, extrusionSettings);
                const extrudedMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ color: 0xFFFF00, side: THREE.DoubleSide });
                const extrudedMesh = new THREE.Mesh(extrudedGeometry, extrudedMaterial);

                // Position the extruded mesh at the clicked coordinates
                extrudedMesh.position.set(x, y + 1, z);
                scene.add(extrudedMesh);
            }
        }
    };
```

Here is what it does, as you can see it just creates flat shapes at weird spots:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLoww.png)